# Fedora 34 VMware Workstation VM Upgraded from Fedora 33 has Audio Crackling

Tags: fedora, pipewire

I use Fedora in a VMware Workstation VM, and today, I upgraded it from 33 to 34. I am having an issue with the audio not playing properly and instead, I just get popping and cracking noises out of my speaker instead. The only sound that sometimes plays properly, but not always, is the "bubble noise" that plays when you adjust the volume level on the volume slider. Everything else just results in crackling.

I found [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1955921) which suggests copying the pipewire configuration elsewhere and reinstalling pipewire, but that has not worked for me. Does anyone have any suggestions? I would have guessed that by now, someone would have seen this on VMware, but that does not appear to be the case so far.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using VMware Workstation 16.1.1 latest?  Can you update or reinstall the VMware Tools?  Are your host Audio driver and BIOS up to date?

Comment: @John I am indeed using VMware Workstation 16.1.1. Sorry I probably should have mentioned it earlier. As for install VMware Tools, I have already tried running `sudo dnf reinstall openvm-tools` but that did not solve anything.

As for my host audio driver and BIOs, yes, everything is up to date. I should also note that on Fedora 33, the audio worked just fine.

Comment: I will keep looking around. I have VMware Workstation 16.1.1 and several Windows and Linux machines and sound is normal.

Comment: @John Thank you! Are you using `openvm-tools` or do you use the one that comes bundled with VMware? I've tried to install the one that comes with VMware as well, but haven't had any luck with it, but even so, perhaps it would give me an idea for something to try?

Comment: I am using the VMware Tools on all machines.

Comment: @John Alright, thank you! I tried switching over to them just now. No luck.

Comment: Have you tried going back to pulseaudio? `sudo dnf swap --allowerasing pipewire-pulseaudio pulseaudio ` https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/DefaultPipeWire

Comment: @Nemo That is not something I had tried, but either way, I have a working solution now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution!

The issue can be fixed by uncommenting and editing the following values in `/etc/pipewire/media-session.d/alsa-monitor.conf`:

```
api.alsa.period-size = 256
api.alsa.headroom = 8192
```

Source: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/469#note_768518

Comment: Where is that file located on Fedora 35? `/etc/pipewire/` doesn't exist.