# Fedora 34 can't install the boot loader configuration

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, bootloader

The Error is:
**"The following error occurred while installing the boot loader. The system will not be bootable."**

I  have a problem installing Fedora 34, every time it tries to install the boot loader, this window appears. I don't know what to do. Please Help

I am trying to install Fedora 34 alongside my Windows 10 partition, and UEFI mode.

Attached three log files:

- Anaconda.log
- Storage.log
- Program1.log
- And a photo of the Message

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yG0vGHk5gS7fhX0YxoKS7W4aFp0VHnIT?usp=sharing

Comment: Perhaps try Fedora V33.  There was a thread I posted to recently where the author of the post upgraded a Fedora 33 Virtual Machine to Fedora 34 and it did not work properly.

Comment: I used Fedora 33, but I broke it, so I wanted to install a clean installation. I tried to install on VirtualBox, but I couldn't even run the Live media. Do you @John have the link to the thread?

Comment: Here is the other thread. Author got it working  https://superuser.com/questions/1646216/fedora-34-vmware-workstation-vm-upgraded-from-fedora-33-has-audio-crackling'

Comment: Thank you! @John

Comment: Could you include the screenshot via imgur? Also include the logs in full in the question. This is so that in the future if you ever delete the screenshot, other people will still be able to get the question context.